# HTTP 502.5 - ASP.NET Core cannot start in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Quiero correr una aplicacion Asp Core pero dadoa este error he hecho muchos cambios dentro de mi proyecto le agregue estas lineas al Porgram.cs

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .Build();
```

Pero no vi errores o un log que reflejara el error que ocurrio, entonces lo ejecute desde consola y este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Mi pregunta es que puedo hacer en este caso?